# CakePHP SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, sql-server-2012

Estou com um grande problema aqui.

Tenho uma aplicação feita em cakephp hospedada na locaweb em servidor windows.

Está acontecendo o seguinte problema: O método save de NENHUM model está funcionando. No debug eu busco o erro de validation error e de invalide fields. Nenhum me retorna problema e quando busco a ultima query do model e coloco diretamente no banco eu consigo inserir e dar update em qualquer tabela.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

exemplo de query retornada:

```
INSERT INTO [categorias] ([cod], [nome], [garantia]) VALUES (N'teste', N'teste', 3)
```

Diretamente no banco funciona, alguma ideia do porque não funciona pela aplicação?

Obrigado!

Comment: O utilizador da base de dados está com permissões para escrever?

Comment: Está sim. Uso o mesmo usuário pra conectar ao banco pelo sql management studio, e lá consigo fazer insert e update, mas pela aplicação não é possível. Meus models não retornam nenhum erro. Pode ser algum problema de relacionamento? Ou será que é na própria aplicação?